# Hide non-selected items in a list

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items which are generated by a SharePoint control and thus I don't have any control over the markup.

The only thing I have to go on is an `<li>` with a class of 'selected'. By default all the other nested items are shown but I only want to show the trail from the parent. For any nodes that are part of the line I want to show siblings but not descendents.

Please see this JSFiddle for what I need to do...
http://jsfiddle.net/QLbAS/4/

Thanks

```
//logic i think should be 
// get all items in the hierarchy to this particular item
// for each item in step above check to see if there are sibling nested lists
// if yes then hide the items
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $("li").hide();
    $("li.selected").parents("li").andSelf().each(function(index,elem) {
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().show();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLbAS/9/)

Comment: Hi, that's not too far away I don't think. It works for the selected node in the example but not if you move the selected node up a level.

Comment: @ringo747: I moved it up one level and made a slight change to the selector (I didn't notice before that both the `li` and the `a` tags had the class `.selected`. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QLbAS/8/) what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. You are correct that it is the li.selected that I want to target. 

In the fiddle if you were to select an element further up the tree as active then I will still want to show the relevant list items below that node. 

Sorry for bad explanation - it is rather messy.

Comment: @ringo747: Ahh...okay, I missed that. Should be doable. You could add a `$("li.selected *").show();` to select all descendants of the selected item and make them visible. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QLbAS/10/)

Comment: Almost there... in order to show only the next level of navigation I have changed the fiddle to this
http://jsfiddle.net/QLbAS/11/

Many thanks for helping out - I'd never have worked this out. Should I put this inside the DOM ready function or do I not even need that?